# How would I code this basic C++ program more cleanly, to run more efficiently or to return a more precise figure?

Tags: c++

It is supposed to evaluate e^pi - pi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
long double Pie();
long double Factorial(double n);
long double E();

int main()
{
    long double answer = pow(E(),Pie()) - Pie();
    cout << setprecision(20);
    cout << answer;

    return 0;
}
long double Pie()
{
    long double a = 1;
    long double b = (1 / sqrtl(2));
    long double t = (1.0 / 4.0);
    long double p = 1;

    long double aPlaceholder;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        aPlaceholder = a;
        a = (a + b) / 2;
        b = sqrtl(aPlaceholder * b);
        t = t - p * (aPlaceholder - a) * (aPlaceholder - a);
        p = 2 * p;
    }
    long double nicePie;
    nicePie = (a + b) * (a + b) / (4 * t);
    return nicePie;
}

long double E()
{
    long double e = 0;
    for(double i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    e += 1.0 / Factorial(i);
    return e;
}

long double Factorial(double n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    return 1;
    int i = n - 1;
    while (i > 0)
    {
      n *= i;
      i--;
    }
    return n;
}
```

The scenario is that I want to evaluate e, raise it to the power of pi, and then subtract pi from the result and then print the answer to the screen. Another aspect to the scenario is that this is a basic C++ program.

Comment: The first thing, that comes to my mind - execute `Pie` only once and store its value, then pass it in the calculation of `answer`.

Comment: Are `Pie` and `E` always the same? If so (and it looks like this) - why don't you precompute them and directly use them? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What's wrong with `exp(atan(1)*4) - atan(1)*4`?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is why calculate Pi at all, why not just either get the value from a library or simply declare a constant `pie = 3.1415926535...`

Comment: I'm not sure how much this will matter, but try initializing your double as `long double e(0.0);`

Answer (score 4):

`cmath` provides ***π*** and ***e*** as predefined constants as `M_PI` and `M_E` accurate within the precision of `double`, but it's not mandatory by C++ standard.

You can just do `double pi = acos(-1);`

Comment: It undoubtedly does in some implementations, but it's not required by standard C++ and its inclusion is nowhere close to universal.

Answer (score 4):

- `<cmath>` provides `double long exp(double long)`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/exp/ as well as the Pi constant `M_PI` in double precision.
- Boost provides Pi in `long double` precision :
   `const long double pi = boost::math::constants::pi<long double>();`

That being said there is some calculus in your code that you do multiple times while it is not needed:

- `Pie` is called twice.
- In `E()`, `Factorial` is called at every iteration while you could multiply the previous result with `i`.

.

```
long double E()
{
  long double e = 0;
  long double fact_i = 1;
  for(double i = 1; i < 20; i++)
  {
    fact_i *= i;
    e += 1.0 / fact_i;
  }
  return e;
}
```